# Linking CSS file in Laravel 5.5 does not work

Tags: css, laravel-5

I created a new project using **Laravel 5.5** and I am trying to link my CSS but it does not work. When I put some CSS codes nothing happens to my page. I already tried clearing my cache. I do not know whats wrong, please help. Here is how I linked my css in my app.blade.php

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is my css code:

```
body{
    background-color: black;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the css inside a css file in your resource folder, you need to build it with NPM:

```
npm install
```

then

```
npm run watch
```

If you directly put it in the public folder, have you checked to make sure you're linking the right file? Also, try ctrl + f5 to hard refresh

Answer (score 0):

The file **style.css** must be there in the required location. By default it will be:

> ***/public/css/style.css***

Otherwise if you have changed the resource path to your web server root, then it could be:

> ***/css/style.css***